# Wire the ALPS RWM SCS Speed control Switch

Tags: control-system, speed

I recently purchased an ALPS RWM SCS Speed Control switch board. This will speed control an ALPS Standard Rod Wrapped 110 VAC motor . The board has. B500k POT, capacitor, resistor and TiAC components with a serial CW-110220. No wiring diagram was provided and need some assistance.  How do I wire up this ALPs switch board?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The switch board has two contacts to wire to the motor and to my 110 vac supply .  Please tell me how to wire to these contacts ? Do I tie the negative lead from the motor and one lead from the power supply together and then tie the positive side of supply to one contact and the other to motor lead ??